# SharePoint 2013. Workflow Manager won't start

Tags: workflow-foundation, sharepoint-2013

Starting Workflow Manager Service via url (or through net start WorkflowServiceBackend) fails and in the EventLog I read this:

> Unhandled exception in AppDomain: 
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.FatalException: An unrecoverable error
>   occurred. For diagnostic purposes, this English message is associated
>   with the failure: 'A required Workflow Manager configuration
>   'WorkflowServiceScopeSnapshotProcessBatchSize' is not present. Please
>   add this configuration value.'. ---> System.IO.InvalidDataException: A
>   required Workflow Manager configuration
>   'WorkflowServiceScopeSnapshotProcessBatchSize' is not present. Please
>   add this configuration value.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)

I didn't manage to find on MSDN or anywhere else on the Internet what this parameters is and how to configure it.

If anyone has come across this issue, I'll really appreciate if you pour some light on this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the exact reason for this error, but I also had it (only when starting my Workflow TestHost).  I added the following entries to the WFResourceManagementDB.dbo.WorkflowServiceConfig table:

```
USE WFResourceManagementDB
INSERT INTO WorkflowServiceConfig VALUES('WorkflowServiceScopeSnapshotProcessBatchSize', '50')
INSERT INTO WorkflowServiceConfig VALUES('WorkflowServiceScopeSnapshotProcessLoopInterval', '00:05:00')
INSERT INTO WorkflowServiceConfig VALUES('WorkflowServiceSuspendedInstanceRetentionDuration', '00:30:00')
INSERT INTO WorkflowServiceConfig VALUES('WorkflowServiceMaxInstanceCompressedSizeKB', '5120')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't think setting values directly in the database is a good idea, it is not supported either, as far as I know. Instead, I suggest to use the Set-WFServiceConfiguration PowerShell cmdlet as described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/feseca/2015/02/27/error-publishing-a-sharepoint-workflow-into-workflow-manager-exceeds-the-maximum-number-of-arguments/